# Cloudcontrol (first webpage Error 403)

Tags: cloudcontrol

my problem is, as you seen in the title, that i cant open my webpage.
I did it all with github and uploaded it to my repository.

https://github.com/Felixthm/Test

after i uploaded it, i went to cloudcontrol (cloudcontrol.com, can just add 2 Links because im new ^^) to the quickstart and followed the instructions.

After the instruction i opened http://felixtestet.cloudcontrolled.com 
and got the 403 error. The rest of my internet is working, so i dont know what im doing wrong :/

Thx in advance

Greetings

Fussel

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an index.html or index.php, so accessing / does not work. http://felixtestet.cloudcontrolled.com/unbenannt.html works. Check out https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php/blob/master/README.md for the different ways to configure Apache and PHP.

Comment: I found my mistake. First i forgot at my test the index, like you said. At my second Project i just had to change Index.html in index.html, lowercase... Thx for you help :)